# Selenium does't open firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'm trying use selenium and firefox, but it's just open the browser and set this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbpmb.png)

With Chrome is ok.

This is the code:

`from selenium import webdriver`
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "c:/my-apps/geckodriver.exe")

Thanks very much

Comment: Note: in console there are errors about chrome, but I am using geckodriver/firefox.

Comment: Hey can you post the html in question, it's mostly due to a timing issue since firefox tends to be slower than chrome. I'd suggest using webdriver waits to look for that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to find any element in an `HTML` page that does not exist, `NoSuchElementException` will be raised.

[image]

---

#### First Possible Solution:

You need to import

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Then you can use `try except` block

```
try:
  your_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='loginForm:username']")
  your_element.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
  pass
```

---

#### Second Possible Solution:

Without importing anything, checking whether that element exist, if it does then it will be clicked

```
your_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='loginForm:username']")
if len(your_element) > 0:
    elem[0].click()
```

Comment: Helo! If I ignore that element, I can't login...

Comment: @ElaineSilva, the problem is maybe because of not entering texts in text fields, It seems actions are too fast that's why it is skipping. you can use `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` to make sure browser loads completely before `geckodriver` is able to fully grow.

Comment: you can also use                                                                                                         import time
time.sleep(5)

Answer (score 0):

HEY You can use this code as given below

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('URL')
```

I think you should put your ***geckodriver*** in the same folder where you are coding

and if this does not work you need to upgrade **geckodriver**

Comment: Helo! The geckodrive is the last version and is in the folder of the app

Answer (score 0):

HEY According to your ERROR
when you open the website your 1 element is not correct
you need to change your 1 element of your website

Comment: Hi! It's correct, with Chrome I can find it. In the firefox inspetor I find it too

Comment: try this import time you need to import time first and write the code *time.sleep(5)* so it will wait for 5 second so that it get ditect the element

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(self.driver,60) 
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#loginForm:username"))).send_keys("a")
```

Generally Firefox is a tad slower than Chrome so your issue may be timing for find elements. What is recommended is waiting for the element to be clickable and then proceeding to send keys to it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```